# Linux file compression and extraction (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos, files, tar

I seem to be having an issue with file extraction on centOS 7.

Scenario:

PC1 is collecting .csv and .txt extension files into one directory, every 5 minutes everything inside this directory is tarballed and compressed into a .tar.gz file using a cron job. So the file looks something like the below:

pc1_'date_timestamp'.tar.gz

These .tar.gz files are then moved to a remote server.

Question:

On the remote server, how do you extract these .tar.gz files to retrieve the .txt and .csv files into one singular file and how do you delete / remove these extracted file to reclaim space?

Note: All the .csv and .txt files have unique namining conventions prior to be being tarballed so duplication won't be an issue.

Errors I am seeing:

tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Any advice or assistance will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the exact commands to compress and uncompress files. Also on the source server please run this, `gzip -t file.tar.gz; echo $?` and report the resulting number. Also, make sure whatever script you're using on the remote server has permissions to extract files. You're described two black boxes without giving us any details and we should guess what's going on.

Comment: tar command: tar -cvzf /home/admin/zipped_files/backup_`date "+\%d-\%m-\%Y_\%H-\%M-\%S"`.tar.gz --remove-files /home/admin/created_files/test_*

Unable to extract the files as I recieve this error:

tar -xzf /home/admin/zipped_files/backup_*
tar: /home/admin/zipped_files/backup_02-08-2022_11-51-01.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: /home/admin/zipped_files/backup_02-08-2022_11-57-01.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

gzip -t file.tar.gz; echo $?
Output is 1

Comment: This command looks wrong: `tar -xzf /home/admin/zipped_files/backup_*`. You're using the first found tar archive to extract others which obviously don't exist. Please extract tar files one by one instead.